# IE 9 Mobile doesn't like my valid SSL

Tags: certificate

I am using a Nokia Lumia 800 with WinPho 7.5 to aid the development of our website. Currently, we have a valid VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation certificate, which supports two domains:

```
www.direct-travel.co.uk
m.direct-travel.co.uk (not live)
```

When I navigate to a secure URL on www.direct-travel.co.uk, IE Mobile complains about the SSL:

"It looks like the security certificate wasn't issued by a trusted certificate authority."

Certificate details:

```
Issued to: www.direct-travel.co.uk
Issued by: VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL SC CA
Valid from 24/01/2011 to 24/01/2013
```

It also has a SAN for our other domain:

```
Subject Alternative Name: DNS Name=m.direct-travel.co.uk
                          DNS Name=www.direct-travel.co.uk
```

**Are there any known issues with WinPho / IE9 Mobile when using Extended Validation certificates? Are there any fixes to the issues?**

*I can't really just manually add the certificate to the cert store on the phone, as real customers would encounter these same issues, so I need to find a solution that just works by default.*

Comment: Maybe you should ask this on stackoverflow. To me it is more a dev orientated question

Comment: Have you checked your site configuration?  This is worth a shot: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Comment: @paradroid - Thanks, that site helped me figure this issue out, our site is not performing a redirect from .domain to www.domain, which does work on desktop class browsers, but not on mobile browsers.

Comment: Facing the same issue Please provide the Redirection rule which you use in you on web server to resolve the issue? Thanks AK

Answer (score 3):

This was due to our web server not performing an initial redirect from a .domain through to our www.domain.